# How to retrieve XML element childs as a string in XQuery

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic

I'm using MarkLogic database and I want to retrieve XML element's value, including it's child element tags and values in a string using XQuery.

e.g. I have text element.

```
<text_element>
   This <p>is</p> random <b> text </b>
</text_element>
```

How can I get the value `This <p>is</p> random <b> text </b>`.
With `xs:string(text_element)` I can get `This is random text` but I need the child node element tags as well.

Comment: In terms of XPath/XQuery `text_element/node()` should select all child nodes of that element and usually the result you see is then a serialization of those nodes. If you want to explicitly serialize to a string then XPath 3.1/XQuery 3.1 offers a `serialize` function e.g. `serialize(text_element/node())` but I don't know whether Marklogic has a similar function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`node()` should work for your example.  If this were deeper, then some level of recursion would likely be needed.

```
<text_element>
  This <p>is</p> random <b> text </b>
</text_element>/node()
```

Result is a sequence of 4 items:

```
This 

<p>is</p>

random 

<b> text </b>
```

EDIT:  Below was added after comments. A cleaner version serialized:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com" at "/MarkLogic/functx/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xqy";

let $element := functx:change-element-ns-deep(
   <text_element xmlns="llama">
       This <p>is</p> random <b> text </b>
    </text_element>,
    "", "")

return fn:normalize-space(fn:string-join(($element/node() !xdmp:quote(.)), ""))
```

Resulting in a clean string:

`This <p>is</p> random <b> text </b>`

Comment: If you want a string with the XML elements serialized as strings, then can use `xdmp:quote()` i.e. `/xdmp:quote(node())`

Comment: Thank you for answers. The only issue now when I run the code is that XML element schema attributes are added to the child tags. e.g. `<p xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.standard.no/sarepta/product/1.0">`. Is there an option for one of the functions to not add these attributes?

Comment: OK. I updated with a simple way to remove the namespace. Could have taken a few approaches - I chose to simply strip it up-front.